# How to calculate short-time autocorrelation of a speech signal?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, signal-processing, autocorrelation

I wrote 2 functions for deriving the short-time zero crossing rate and short-time energy of a speech signal. I'm unsure of how to write one for short-time auto-correlation in python using hamming windows.

Here is how I derived short-time energy:

```
def ste(x, win):
    """Compute short-time energy"""
    if isinstance(win, str):
        win = sg.get_window(win, max(1, len(x) // 8))
    win = win/len(win)
    return sg.convolve(x**2, win**2, mode='same')
```

Here's a function for calculuating autocorrelation, but not short-time autocorr.

```
def estimated_autocorrelation(x):

    n = len(x)
    variance = x.var()
    x = x-x.mean()
    r = np.correlate(x, x, mode = 'full')[-n:]
    assert np.allclose(r, np.array([(x[:n-k]*x[-(n-k):]).sum() for k in range(n)]))
    result = r/(variance*(np.arange(n, 0, -1)))
    return result
```